# How to access video streams which are transferred by WebRTC in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

guys.
I want to access my video streams which are generated by WebRTC in Chrome.
It seems impossible for javaScript to access my streams, am I right?
How to deal with?

Comment: what specific programming issues are you having? What do you want to do with your streams that you are finding issues with?

Answer (score 0):

How about you start by looking at this very simple tutorial:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

It will teach you the basics of WebRTC web interface, then you can move up from there ;)